# System sluggish after Monterey update

Tags: macbook-pro, monterey

I recently updated to Monterey and my entire system has been noticably sluggish since.

Without trying to use this forum to complain, I just wondered anyone knows of fixes to issues with the new OS that are making my Mac so degraded in performance **OR** how I might revert to the previous OS ?

My system is a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015), 2.7 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5, 8 GB 1867 MHz DDR3, Intel Iris Graphics 6100 1536 MB.

My issues with the system performance that I described above are observed in day-to-day use. It is that noticably BAD.

UPDATE:
My issues are going from BAD to WORSE.

Prior to posting my question I had constantly experienced typing delays where I get the busy wheel after which all my typing is afterwards output.

But now, my trackpad seizes up and becomes unresponsive for a few seconds.

Comment: What is the year and type of your Mac? Have you tested your system with any benchmarking software such as GeekBench or NovaBench?

Comment: I find that for a couple of days (depending on usage) after a major macOS upgrade the system runs hotter and sometimes slower. It is an unfortunate side effect that some people notice. This may be happening to you and, with luck, it will fix itself in a day or two.

Comment: @Alper: I answered your questions above

Comment: @SteveChambers: It's been a week or longer since I updated. I am begining to suspect throtteling.

Comment: @SteveChambers: Yes, I believe the previous version I had was Big Sur

Comment: I feel for you, but afraid I have no advice to offer that will restore performance. I had a similar issue with a 2011 macbook pro when I tried to upgrade it. to a newer macOS. It never recovered from the upgrade. I recently upgraded to Ubuntu, and the old machine is quite zippy now. I don't know if a 'Linux upgrade' is possible for your machine as Apple continues to make it more difficult to install and run Linux with things like T2 chip, built-in SSD, etc. It seems to be very difficult developing drivers for the proprietary chips & devices. Good luck.

Comment: Also know that after a point in time (7 years???), Apple will simply decline to support your machine in any way - no hardware, no software - not even batteries. If you're interested in keeping your machine viable with Apple software, your window of opportunity may not last much longer.